# C++ pass object by reference

Tags: c++

What is the mechanism behind this code? Why is the copy constructor not called?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo{
public:
    Foo(){
        i = 0;
        cout << "Constructor is called " << i << "\n";
    };
    Foo(int is){
        i = is;
        cout << "Constructor is called " << i << "\n";
    }
    Foo(const Foo &f) {
        cout << "Copy constructor is called\n";
    }
    ~Foo(){
        cout << "Destructor is called " << i << "\n";
    };
    int i;
};

void loadobj(Foo &f) {
    f = Foo(1);
    return;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Foo f;
    loadobj(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor is called 0
Constructor is called 1
Destructor is called 1
Destructor is called 1
```

This is my view of the whole process:

Obj1 is created in main loop. Then loadobj call copy constructor, create obj2 inside loadobj. Is it correct?

Comment: Copy-constructor is not called, because `f = Foo(1);` is an assignment. `Foo f2 = Foo(1);` would probably call a copy-constructor

Comment: You have two destructor calls, so what do you think?

Comment: I don't understand the first question.  You know the answer is 2 as there are two constructor calls and two destructor calls.

Comment: Two objects. But why is the second destructor is not 0? I thought I have obj1 in main function, then a copy constructor is called to create obj2 inside loadobj

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't understand the mechanism, why things are happening this way.

Comment: @DzungNguyen "Second destructor is not 0" because you are passing `f` by reference to `loadobj()`. This means that the member `i` belonging to the original `f` in main is the same as the `f` in `loadobj()`.

Comment: OK, maybe you're missing that this is an assignment: `f = Foo(1);`

Comment: So I'm having 2 objects, and somehow they're linked together through reference? The code will have segmentation fault if  I change int to int* with dynamic memory.

Comment: It's calling an assignment operator, which is effectively `Foo& Foo::operator = (const Foo& rhs) { i = rhs.i; return *this; }`.  Since the object contains only POD members (a single int), the compiler is able to generate an assignment operator for you, despite it not being explicitly declared or defined.

Comment: Ah! this is what I'm looking for. So instead of copy constructor it calls assignment operator!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no copy constructor involved. Two default constructors and an assignment.

Tried to explain it below:

```
<void loadobj(Foo &f) {
    f = Foo(1); // Foo(1) is a temporary object 
                // so it calls default constructor with argument = 1, i.e. called with 1
                // Then the temporary is assigned to f.
                // That is NOT a constructor - just an assignment
                // Then calls destrutcor for temporary
    return; 


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Foo f;  // calls default constructor with no arguments, i.e. called with 0
    loadobj(f);
    return 0; // calls destructor for f
}
```